# AVAssetExportSession not working in ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

In my application I am combining two audio files using AVAssetExportSession and it works fine in earlier ios versions.But in ios5 device its not working. What i am getting is an error

```
AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo=0x1df1c0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}
```

The code that I use for exporting is given below

Did anyone experience the same issue? Please provide your valuable suggestions.
I am in an urgent need to fix this issue..

```
//Export function to export the combined audios as one.
-(void)exportAudioFile:(AVComposition*)combinedComposition
{
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:combinedComposition
                                                                           presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    NSArray *presets =[AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:combinedComposition];
    NSLog(@"presets======%@",presets);
    NSLog (@"can export: %@", exportSession.supportedFileTypes);
    NSArray *dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [dirs objectAtIndex:0];
    exportPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CombinedNew.m4a"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
    exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
    exportSession.outputURL = exportURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog (@"i is in your block, exportin. status is %d",
               exportSession.status);
        switch (exportSession.status) 
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: 
            {
                // log error to text view
                NSError *exportError = exportSession.error;
                DEBUG_LOG(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);
                [self enableUI];
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: 
            {
                DEBUG_LOG(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                DEBUG_LOG(@"Completed export");
                exportSuccess = YES;
                if (recorderFilePath) 
                {
                    NSError *finalurlError;
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:recorderFilePath  error:&finalurlError];
                    finalurlError = nil;
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[exportURL path] toPath:recorderFilePath error:&finalurlError];
                }
                isExported = YES;
                fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];  
                [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updatePlayerForUrl:) withObject:fileUrl];
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: 
            {   
                DEBUG_LOG(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown");                 
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: 
            { 
                DEBUG_LOG(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting");                 
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: 
            { 
                DEBUG_LOG(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled");
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: 
            { 
                DEBUG_LOG(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");                 
                break;
            }
            default: 
            { 
                DEBUG_LOG(@"didn't get export status");                
                break;
            }

        };
    }];
    [exportSession release];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I sorted out the answer for myself and would like to share it with others who experience the same problem.

The problem is that for some reason the `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` is not working properly in ios5. Substituting it with `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` solved the issue.
But it takes longer to export now.

Comment: Anybody have any idea why AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough is not working? Its causing a lot of time delay while exporting with AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a way around it is to use AVAssetWriter directly and not use AVAssetExportSession.  Please please please, file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com so that maybe it gets fixed in the next rev of iOS5.  (I filed one of my own, but the more the merrier.)

Comment: I have also filed a bug report. I wonder how apps which require this (eg: DJ apps) are coping with iOS5.1

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I found that using .mov as the file extension, then renaming it back to mp3 seems to work. I dont need to do this for m4a files.